# Search item in an array in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have an array and I want to check whether a particular item is existing or not.

My array looks,

[image]

I want to check "Apple" existing or not... if not exist push it to array.

Comment: You can use `angular.foreach` to compare object keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function. Example:

```
var arr = [{title: 'Orange'}, {title: 'Apple'}, {title: 'Kiwi'}, {title: 'Banana'}];

function appleExists(){
    return arr.some(elem => elem.title == 'Apple'); 
}

alert(appleExists());
//if (!appleExists()) arr.push({title: 'Apple'});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4qz5v7w0/1/

Answer (score 1):

Just write a basic javascript `for`-loop:

```
var found = false;
var toCheck = { parameters: [], title: "Apple" };

for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i].title === toCheck.title) {
        found = true;
        break; // no need to search further
    }
}

if (!found) {
    myArray.push(toCheck);
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/emovfgtr/)

Comment: any idea without for loop ?

Answer (score 1):

I do this sort of things with [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/)

```
_.contains(fruits, function(f) { return f.title === 'Apple';})
```

There may be some more concise ways to do this with underscore too.

PS: I looked at the [docs](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere) docs and I saw the more concise way I had mentioned:

```
_.findWhere(fruits, {title: 'Apple'});
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the **indexOf** method:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
var a = fruits.indexOf("Apple");
```

Comment: This won't work, because he has an array of objects, not just plain strings